# How two group the sum of two queries?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by, subquery

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
(
    (
        SELECT PRICE
        FROM APPLES
        WHERE YEAR(DATE) = d.year
    )
    +
    (
        SELECT PRICE
        FROM BANANAS
        WHERE YEAR(DATE) = d.year
    )
) AS 'Result'
FROM(
    SELECT 2017 AS 'year' UNION
    SELECT 2018 AS 'year' UNION
    SELECT 2019 AS 'year' UNION
    SELECT 2020 AS 'year'
)d
```

I want to find a better way to group this query and optimize it, is it possible?

Comment: Is it slow? You need to ensure that all subselects return single value - use `TOP 1` or `MAX()`, otherwise nothing to improve. Well, database design would be bad, if bananas and apples would be real table names and they would contain single record per year :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, there are several rows in each of the two tables for each year, and you want to sum them.

Here is one approach using lateral joins:

```
select y.yr, coalesce(a.price, 0) + coalesce(b.price, 0) price
from (values (2017), (2018), (2019), (2020)) as y(yr)
cross apply (
    select sum(a.price) total_price 
    from apples a
    where a.date >= datefromparts(y.yr, 1, 1) and a.date < datefromparts(y.yr + 1, 1, 1)
) a
cross apply (
    select sum(b.price) total_price 
    from bananas b
    where b.date >= datefromparts(y.yr, 1, 1) and b.date < datefromparts(y.yr + 1, 1, 1)
) b
```

An important thing to note is that this query optimizes the lookups in the two tables: it would take advantage of indexes on the date columns. It also allows missing years in any of the two tables.

If there is just one row per year, in each of the two tables, then we can dispense aggregation, and use straight left joins:

```
select y.yr, coalesce(a.price, 0) + coalesce(b.price, 0) price
from (values (2017), (2018), (2019), (2020)) as y(yr)
left join apples a
    on  a.date >= datefromparts(y.yr, 1, 1) 
    and a.date < datefromparts(y.yr + 1, 1, 1)
left join bananas b
    on  b.date >= datefromparts(y.yr, 1, 1) 
    and b.date < datefromparts(y.yr + 1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `VALUES` and `JOIN` with SARGable date logic?

```sql
SELECT V.[Year],
       A.Price + B.Price AS OverallPrice
FROM (VALUES(2017),(2018),(2019),(2020))V([Year])
     JOIN dbo.Apples A ON A.[Date] >= DATEFROMPARTS(V.[Year],1,1)
                      AND A.[Date] < DATEFROMPARTS(V.[Year]+1,1,1)
     JOIN dbo.Bananas B ON B.[Date] >= DATEFROMPARTS(V.[Year],1,1)
                       AND B.[Date] < DATEFROMPARTS(V.[Year]+1,1,1);
```

If a table might not have a row for that year, then use a `LEFT JOIN`, and you'll need to use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` in the `SELECT`.